# Technical drawing glossary: How do you translate "cross section" (of a boat)?

Tags: translation, word-choice, word-usage, english-to-german

I'm designer and 3D artist and I'm translating my portfolio in German. 
I'm uncertain how to translate some specific design words, in this case:

(of a boat, yacht)

- side cross section

I found *Abschnitt*, *Ausschnitt* and *Sektion*, but there is no evidence when I try to check on Google images: for example, when I write *yacht sektion* I don't find *yacht cross sections*.

PS: I even didn't find the word in any German glossary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common translation will probably be "**Querschnitt**". This is any view that shows how an object would look cut in half, usually along a central vertical axis.
You can say "Seitenquerschnitt" to emphasise that this is a *side* cross section, but since this should be rather obvious in your case (unless you're designing a very unsual yacht) it will sound like "side cross section seen from the side (not from above or below)" Duh! :)

"Seitenansicht" and "Seitenriss" both mean a mere "side view" that does not reveal the interior.

If you're talking about a building, "Aufriss" is correct ("elevation" - also usually not showing the interior). "Grundriss" is a building's floor plan.

"Sektion" is more or less correct, but rarely used - sounds rather medical to me. I wouldn't recommend it.

"Ausschnitt" usally just means "detail" but can sometimes refer to a bit of the object being cut away to show the interior. But this is never a cross section - I suppose you'd say "with a section of the hull removed" or something.

"Abschnitt" means "section" in the sense of "part".

Comment: Note for a boat, for example, a *side cross section* is a *Längsschnitt*, while a *Front/Rear cross section* is a *Querschnitt*. English thinks "seen from the side, then cut into", German thinks "cut lengthwise, then look at cut"

Answer (score 2):

Aufriss, Seitenriss, Kreuzriss, Grundriss - may depend on the exact direction of view. (As you say "side cross section", it should be "Seitenriss" or as is apparently more modern: "Seitenansicht von links bzw. rechts")

Cf. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalprojektion